# Google Place API for Android: can't select place with the picker of Place Picker

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I added to my android application Place Picker. When you know the address of the place you want to pick and fill the research bar, it works. 
But I want that the user has the possibility to choose the place of his choice in using the red picker and this part doesn't  work.

When you pick a place with the red picker and click "Select this location" like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7id8i.png).

We can't select the place. The "Select" button is greyed out. Like you can observe [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDfGt.png).

Of course I have enabled the Google Place Android API and Google Maps Android API on the Google Developer Console.

I searched the reason (and a solution) on stackoverflow. I found some posts saying to put the API key that we can found on the google developer console inside:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

I did it but no positive result.

Then I tried to do again the implementation of Place Picker from scratch, without success.

This is the code where I use Place Picker:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_location);
    Button chooseLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_location);
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        final Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
        chooseLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);
            }
        });

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO handle exception!
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO handle exception!
    }


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toast = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
            latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't find anymore solution to try on the internet. It's why I write this question. Does anybody have any idea why this doesn't work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't enabled "Google Places API for Android" in your API console, Enable it. I have faced same problem once. I solved using the above solution.